# Get a data frame from a part of a string

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, substring

I have the market information as a string like this:

```
{"POLISUSDT": {"name": "POLISUSDT", "min_amount": "0.5", "maker_fee_rate": "0.003", "taker_fee_rate": "0.003", "pricing_name": "USDT", "pricing_decimal": 4, "trading_name": "POLIS", "trading_decimal": 8}, "XPRBTC": {"name": "XPRBTC", "min_amount": "100", "maker_fee_rate": "0.003", "taker_fee_rate": "0.003", "pricing_name": "BTC", "pricing_decimal": 10, "trading_name": "XPR", "trading_decimal": 8}, "PSPUSDT": {"name": "PSPUSDT", "min_amount": "5", "maker_fee_rate": "0.003", "taker_fee_rate": "0.003", "pricing_name": "USDT", "pricing_decimal": 4, "trading_name": "PSP", "trading_decimal": 8}, "KAVAUSDT": {"name": "KAVAUSDT", "min_amount": "0.5", "maker_fee_rate": "0.003", "taker_fee_rate": "0.003", "pricing_name": "USDT", "pricing_decimal": 4, "trading_name": "KAVA", "trading_decimal": 8}, "CFXUSDT": {"name": "CFXUSDT", "min_amount": "10", "maker_fee_rate": "0.003", "taker_fee_rate": "0.003", "pricing_name": "USDT", "pricing_decimal": 6, "trading_name": "CFX", "trading_decimal": 8}}
```

I want the information of each market, separately. For example, if I call "POLISUSDT", I want to get this data frame :

| min_amount | maker_fee_rate | taker_fee_rate | pricing_name | pricing_decimal | trading_name | trading_decimal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.5 | 0.003 | 0.003 | USDT | 4 | POLIS | 8 |

Comment: There's an error in your string. Please resolve it and update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note I found some issues in parsing your json - there is an extra `}` just before the `message` field.

Leaving that aside, if you have the `str` representation of your json (let's call it `json_str`), you can load it in a big dataframe using:

```
import pandas as pd

dt = pd.read_json(json_str).transpose()
```

In this part of the code, you should drop the columns you are not interested in.

You can access any element using:

```
dt.loc[["POLISUSDT"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

After remove error data from sample is possible use dictioanry comprehension with [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
d ={"POLISUSDT": {"name": "POLISUSDT", "min_amount": "0.5", "maker_fee_rate": "0.003", "taker_fee_rate": "0.003", "pricing_name": "USDT", "pricing_decimal": 4, "trading_name": "POLIS", "trading_decimal": 8}, "XPRBTC": {"name": "XPRBTC", "min_amount": "100", "maker_fee_rate": "0.003", "taker_fee_rate": "0.003", "pricing_name": "BTC", "pricing_decimal": 10, "trading_name": "XPR", "trading_decimal": 8}, "PSPUSDT": {"name": "PSPUSDT", "min_amount": "5", "maker_fee_rate": "0.003", "taker_fee_rate": "0.003", "pricing_name": "USDT", "pricing_decimal": 4, "trading_name": "PSP", "trading_decimal": 8}, "KAVAUSDT": {"name": "KAVAUSDT", "min_amount": "0.5", "maker_fee_rate": "0.003", "taker_fee_rate": "0.003", "pricing_name": "USDT", "pricing_decimal": 4, "trading_name": "KAVA", "trading_decimal": 8}, "CFXUSDT": {"name": "CFXUSDT", "min_amount": "10", "maker_fee_rate": "0.003", "taker_fee_rate": "0.003", "pricing_name": "USDT", "pricing_decimal": 6, "trading_name": "CFX", "trading_decimal": 8}}
```

---

```
df = {k: pd.json_normalize(v) for k, v in d.items()}
print (df['POLISUSDT'])
        name min_amount maker_fee_rate taker_fee_rate pricing_name  \
0  POLISUSDT        0.5          0.003          0.003         USDT   

   pricing_decimal trading_name  trading_decimal  
0                4        POLIS                8
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_dict = {col: df[col].drop('name', axis=0).rename(None).to_frame().T for col in df.columns}

print(df_dict['POLISUSDT'])
```

Output:

```
  min_amount maker_fee_rate taker_fee_rate pricing_name pricing_decimal  trading_name  trading_decimal  
0        0.5          0.003          0.003         USDT               4   POLIS               8  

   trading_decimal
```